# Scilab round-off error

Tags: scilab

I cannot solve a problem in Scilab because it get stucked because of round-off errors. I get the message

```
!--error 9999 
Error: Round-off error detected, the requested tolerance (or default) cannot be achieved. Try using bigger tolerances.
at line       2 of function scalpol called by :  
at line       7 of function gram_schmidt_pol called by :  
gram_schmidt_pol(a,-1/2,-1/2)
```

It's a Gram Schmidt process with the integral of the product of two functions and a weight as the scalar product, between -1 and 1.
`gram_schmidt_pol` is the process specially designed for polynome, and `scalpol` is the scalar product described for polynome.

The `a` and `b` are parameters for the weigth, which is `(1+x)^a*(1-x)^b`

The entry is a matrix representing a set of vectors, it works well with the matrix `[[1;2;3],[4;5;6],[7;8;9]]`, but it fails with the above message error on matrix `eye(2,2)`, in addition to this, I need to do it on eye(9,9) !

I have looked for a "tolerance setting" in the menus, there is some in `General->Preferences->Xcos->Simulation` but I believe this is not for what I wan't, I have tried low settings (high tolerance) in it and it hasn't change anything.

So how can I solve this rounf-off problem ?

Feel free to tell me my message lacks of clearness.
Thank you.

*Edit*: Code of the functions :

```
// function that evaluate a polynomial (vector of coefficients) in x
function [y] = pol(p, x) 
    y = 0
    for i=1:length(p)
        y = y + p(i)*x^(i-1)
    end
endfunction

// weight function evaluated in x, parametrized by a and b
// (poids = weight in french)
function [y] = poids(x, a, b)
    y = (1-x)^a*(1+x)^b
endfunction

// scalpol compute scalar product between polynomial p1 and p2
// using integrate, the weight and the pol functions.
function [s] = scalpol(p1, p2, a, b)
    s = integrate('poids(x,a, b)*pol(p1,x)*pol(p2,x)', 'x', -1, 1)
endfunction

// norm associated to scalpol
function [y] = normscalpol(f, a, b)
    y = sqrt(scalpol(f, f, a, b))
endfunction

// finally the gram schmidt process on a family of polynome
// represented by a matrix
function [o] = gram_schmidt_pol(m, a, b)
    [n,p] = size(m)
    o(1:n) = m(1:n,1)/(normscalpol(m(1:n,1), a, b))
    for k = 2:p
        s =0 
        for i = 1:(k-1)
            s = s + (scalpol(o(1:n,i), m(1:n,k), a, b) / scalpol(o(1:n,i),o(1:n,i), a, b) .* o(1:n,i))
        end
        o(1:n,k) = m(1:n,k) - s
        o(1:n,k) = o(1:n,k) ./ normscalpol(o(1:n,k), a, b)
    end
endfunction
```

Comment: Yes they are, I edit the post

Answer (score -1):

By default, Scilab's `integrate` routine tries to achieve absolute error at most 1e-8 and relative error at most 1e-14. This is reasonable, but its treatment of relative error does not take into account the issues that occur when the exact value is zero. (See [How to calculate relative error when true value is zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677852)). For this reason, even the simple

```
integrate('x', 'x', -1, 1)
```

throws an error (in Scilab 5.5.1).

And this is what happens in the process of running your program: some integrals are zero. There are two solutions:

(A) Give up on the relative error bound, by specifying it as 1:

```
integrate('...', 'x', -1, 1, 1e-8, 1)
```

(B) Add some constant to the function being integrated, then subtract from the result:

```
integrate('100 + ... ', 'x', -1, 1) - 200
```

(The latter should work in most cases, though if the integral happens to be exactly -200, you'll have the same problem again)

---

The above works for `gram_schmidt_pol(eye(2,2), -1/2, -1/2)` but for larger, say, `gram_schmidt_pol(eye(9,9), -1/2, -1/2)`, it throws the error "The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent".

It appears that the adaptive integration routine can't handle the functions of the kind you have. A fallback is to use the simple `inttrap` instead, which just applies the trapezoidal rule. Since at x=-1 and 1 the function poids is undefined, the endpoints have to be excluded.

```
function [s] = scalpol(p1, p2, a, b)
    t = -0.9995:0.001:0.9995
    y = poids(t,a, b).*pol(p1,t).*pol(p2,t)
    s = inttrap(t,y)
endfunction
```

In order for this to work, other related functions must be vectorized (* and ^ changed to .* and .^ where necessary):

```
function [y] = pol(p, x) 
    y = 0
    for i=1:length(p)
        y = y + p(i)*x.^(i-1)
    end
endfunction

function [y] = poids(x, a, b)
    y = (1-x).^a.*(1+x).^b
endfunction
```

The result is guaranteed to work, though the precision may be a bit lower: you are going to get some numbers like 3D-16 which are actually zeros.

Comment: Thank you but I'm sorry that both method doesn't work for me.

Comment: Works on my computer with Scilab 5.5.1. The command `gram_schmidt_pol(eye(2,2), -1/2, -1/2)` returns  the matrix 0.5683590    0.  //       0.           0.8080328.

Comment: I have 5.5.2. It sucks, I need it to finish my homework for tomorrow and I'm stucked because of a Scilab problem! grrrr!
If only I could do it in Python or OCaml...

Comment: For me it works for matrices up to eye(6,6), but with eye(7,7) and higher I get a different error: "The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent". My suggestion is to drop `integrate` and use the simpler `inttrap` instead. I'll update the answer in a moment.

Comment: the problem is that I can't generate the function to integrate since it's a product of three functions and some of theme are parameters.